# Break double encryption

Tags: cryptanalysis, block-cipher, meet-in-the-middle-attack

Let $E_k$ : {0,1}$^l$ be a block cipher encryption function with block-size $l$ and key-length $n$.

In class, we saw that a double encryption with two independent keys $E{}'_{k_1k_2}(x)$ = $E_{k_1}(E_{k_2}(x))$,

can be brute-forced in $O(2^n)$ time and $O((l + n)2^n)$ space using the meet-in-the-middle attack:

create a table with $2^n$ entries mapping
keys of length $l$ to entries of length n by encrypting the known plain text $x$ with all possible keys $k_2$,
then search the table by decrypting the corresponding cipher text $c$ using all possible keys $k_1$.

Suppose you only have $O((l + m)2^m)$ space (where $m < n$),
Give an algorithm to break the double
encryption in time $O(2^{2n-m})$.

I am stuck for days, can't figure out the trick that will allow such an efficient algorithm.

Any ideas? Tips? Hints?

This is homework of course.

ADDED:

Is it sufficient to show that if we choose smaller $n$ the encryption will be broken with non neglect-able probability? Or I must show an algorithm that ALWAYS brake the encryption?

Comment: The reason for the [tag:homework] tag not existing were discussed in [Asking homework questions](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/90/asking-homework-questions).

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann , Do you think I should edit my question so it will not look like an homework assignment but more like a cryptographic problem?

Comment: If you can't fit a full table, why not try using a smaller table?

Comment: @YoniHassin, I think the info you added needs to be asked to the professor.

Comment: I encourage you to read the FAQ on homework questions.  In particular, the FAQ asks you to show your work: show us what you've tried so far, where you've gotten stuck, etc.  See also [Paŭlo Ebermann♦'s answer](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/a/98/351).  The problem is your question is too much like "Do my homework for me" and not enough like "Here is my task, I already did this part, and I have now this problem. Here is what I tried, but which didn't work."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: suppose someone told you $n-m$ bits of $k_2$; how much time/space would a meet-in-the-middle attack take then?

Comment: It will take $O(2^{2n-m})$ but with low (non neglectable) probability, while using $n$ entries will have very high probability (almost 1).

Comment: Go through it again: if you know $n-m$ bits of the key, it'll take less than $O(2^{2n-m})$ time; how much exactly?  How much space?  And, once you have that, how do you extend that observation to the case where you weren't given the hint?

Comment: Again, do the exercise: if $k_1$ has $n$ unknown bits, and $k_2$ has $m$ unknown bits, how much time would it take to recover the unknown bits?  How much space?  Once you have answered that question, it should be simple to use that as a black-box to solve the case where both $k_1$ and $k_2$ has $n$ unknown bits.